# size of input of algorithm according to Moore's law

Tags: algorithms

I am reading about algorithms in a book tilted Algorithms by Sanjay DasGupta. Here author mentione as below

> In 1965, computer chip pioneer Gordon E. Moore noticed that transistor
>   density in chips had doubled every year in the early 1960s, and he
>   predicted that this trend would continue. This prediction, moderated
>   to a doubling every 18 months and extended to computer speed, is known
>   as Moore's law. It has held remarkably well for 40 years. And these
>   are the two root causes of the explosion of information technology in
>   the past decades: Moore's law and efcient algorithms.
>
> It would appear that Moore's law provides a disincentive for
>   developing polynomial algorithms. After all, if an algorithm is
>   exponential, why not wait it out until Moore's law makes it feasible?
>   **But in reality the exact opposite happens:** Moore's law is a huge
>   incentive for developing efcient algorithms, because such algorithms
>   are needed in order to take advantage of the exponential increase in
>   computer speed. Here is why. If, for example, an O(2^n) algorithm for
>   Boolean satisability (SAT) were given an hour to run, it would have
>   solved instances with 25 variables back in 1975, 31 variables on the
>   faster computers available in 1985, 38 variables in 1995, and about 45
>   variables with today's machines. Quite a bit of progressexcept that
>   each extra variable requires a year and a half's wait, while the
>   appetite of applications (many of which are, ironically, related to
>   computer design) grows much faster. In contrast, the size of the
>   instances solved by an O(n) or O(n log n) algorithm would be
>   multiplied by a factor of about 100 each decade. In the case of an
>   O(n^2) algorithm, the instance size solvable in a fixed time would be
>   multiplied by about 10 each decade. Even an O(n^6) algorithm,
>   polynomial yet unappetizing, would more than double the size of the
>   instances solved each decade. When it comes to the growth of the size
>   of problems we can attack with an algorithm, we have a reversal:
>   exponential algorithms make polynomially slow progress, while
>   polynomial algorithms advance exponentially fast! For Moore's law to
>   be reected in the world we need efficient algorithms.

My questions on above text

1. How author mentioned that when O(n^2) size of the problem solvable is multipled by 10 times in a decade?
2. How author mentioned that when O(n^6) size of the problem solvable is doubled in a decade?
3. What does author mean by "in reality exact opposite happens"?

Answer (score 0):

The author mentions that every 18 months the size of transistors and the speed of computers doubles. Thus, in 10 years the speed will be doubled 6.66 times which means that after 10 years a computer will be approximately 100 times faster. If the run time of an algorithm is $O(n^2)$ and it was able to solve an instance of size $n$ in the beginning, it will now be 100 times faster and, thus, can solve an instance of size $100^\frac{1}{2} \cdot n$ since $(100^\frac{1}{2} \cdot n)^2 = 100 \cdot n^2$. Similarly, an $O(n^6)$ algorithm can now solve an instance of size $100^\frac{1}{6} \cdot n$ since $(100^\frac{1}{6} \cdot n)^6 = 100 \cdot n^6$. Note that $100^\frac{1}{2} = 10$ and $100^\frac{1}{6} \approx 2$.

By "in reality exact opposite happens" the author refers to the fact that you could expect Moore's observation to make exponential time algorithms more suitable in the future. But with his examples of poylnomial time algorithms he shows that the improvement in running time is much bigger for polynomial time algorithms than it is for exponential time algorithms, and therefore it is worth to focus on polynomial time algorithms.